# How to find out about company turnover rates?

Tags: job-search, job-offer, new-job, job-change, job-satisfaction

Is there a reference / lookup for employee turnover rates, i.e. the ratio of employees leaving the company to the ratio of those hired?

This would be a very solid reference to how well the company is liked by the employees. There are indirect ways to come up with some figure on LinkedIn, but it is restricted to the LinkedIn records, also not any practical.

Note that this is way different than the company reviews made by their employees. It also draws a different figure than their salary ranges.

//==========================

UPDATE:

Median tenure is interesting but wouldn't tell the same thing.

As to the average of it -- If <1 out of every 10 employees did 40 yrs and all the rest just 6 months, the average tenure would still add up to 4yrs.

Comment: Is this question for research purposes? Is it for the US or some other country? Because some government agencies in some countries keep some stats on that. Or is it for your own job search? Because if it's for your own job search, there are questions you can ask that can uncover this during the interview.

Comment: You need to revise your understanding of medians. If 1% of employees do 40 years and 99% six months, the median is six months. The *mean* is four years, but this is exactly why you shouldn't use the mean for distributions with big outliers.

Comment: You can get some of this data from glassdoor.com

Comment: @Keltari how exactly, i haven't been everywhere on Glassdoor but having seen a hint of company turnover rates

Comment: @PhilipKendall nope - you need to revise your understanding of averages. thx for the hint thou - looks the way you saw to the "fast-reader".

Comment: @StephanBranczyk do you know which bureau has this info in US? in another line - it would be a negative Q to ask in an interview. i wouldn't like that brought up if i were the company

Comment: @ash__999 No, I don't. "Average" and "arithmetic mean" do not mean the same thing; the median is an average just as much as the arithmetic mean is.

Comment: @ash__999 I read the employee reviews.  They will often talk about turnover if its a problem

Comment: @ash__999 Median tenure would tell a lot more than the average. so for your example 0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,40 if this is the length of the employees stay the median would be 0.5 years. The average is 4 years

Answer (score 5):

**LinkedIn Premium has this**

With some companies, LinkedIn will compile “median tenure” figures. You can see this on the company profile page if you have LinkedIn Premium.

[image]

Comment: thx for the interesting figure. pls see update.

Comment: @ash__999 re: your update, please check what a [Median](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median) is